# Add div to table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to add a div-element to a table cell/td by using jquery?
In my HTML code I have have div called s (just for testing):

```
<div id="s">12</div>
```

In my `$(document).ready(function(){` function I I have added the following `$("#sale_graph1").html('<div id="s"></div>');` where `sale_graph1` is the id of the `<td>/cell` i want to add the `<div>`-element to. The cell gets populated with text if I write $("#sale_graph1").text 
so I know it is the right cell I'm operating on. But when trying to add the div content nothing shows up in the cell.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: You're adding an element with no text. Add some text to the element and what you're trying should work just fine: http://jsbin.com/puyuboho/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @BillCriswell: But I want it to add what has been defined in the <div id="s">. So I want the table cell to contain 12 since that is the value of the <div> I add to the cell.

Comment: Oh I see. You are **creating** an element when you put HTML in there, not referencing. I *believe* you want `$("#sale_graph1").html($('#s').html());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This working just fine. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/va5gr/

```
$('#sale_graph1').html("<div id='s'>12</div>");
```

(I've added the css to make it more visible)

If however you want to use the contents of your existing `div#s` then you can do this:

```
$('#sale_graph1').html($('div#s').html());
```

Comment: Heads up: The `div` before the #s is useless and that selector should be quoted.

Comment: Although the `div` part is useless I like to explicitly define the element as well. However thanks for pointing out the missing quotes

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$("#sale_graph1").append($('#s'));
```

and ensure that you have only one element called **sale_graph1**

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
 $("#sale_graph1").html($('#s').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

After this line:

> $("#sale_graph1").html('');

You can add stuff inside your div doing this:

> $("#sale_graph1 #s").text('12'); //to add text

or

> $("#sale_graph1 #s").html('12'); //to add text with html content

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is right? But I think maybe some errors at some place.

You can check it like as follow:
1. check if you got the right dom

```
console.log($('#sale_graph1').length);
```

insure that you can get '1' in the debugger tool's console

2. if you pass first step, then you can do

   `$("#sale_graph1").html('<div id="s">some text</div>');`
   to make sure you add some text in `div#s`
3. then if it dosen't work, you can say the four words;